# How can I check credentials with values in database in MVVM,WPF?

Tags: database, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, credentials

I'm trying to verify the credentials according to the values that I have inserted manually in my db but without any luck.I have a class called"Credentials" which checks the credentials,a "PasswordHelper" class that I use to bind it to the view through dependancy property and my viewmodel which gives me a bad mojo.Here are my classes:
**PasswordHelper.cs**:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;

 namespace LastAndFinalVersion.Helpers
 {
 public static  class PasswordHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundPassword =
     DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BoundPassword", typeof(string),  
  typeof(PasswordHelper), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, 
  OnBoundPasswordChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindPassword = 
   DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "BindPassword", typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordHelper), new 
   PropertyMetadata(false, OnBindPasswordChanged));

    private static readonly DependencyProperty UpdatingPassword =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UpdatingPassword", typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordHelper), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private static void OnBoundPasswordChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox box = d as PasswordBox;

        // only handle this event when the property is attached to a PasswordBox
        // and when the BindPassword attached property has been set to true
        if (d == null || !GetBindPassword(d))
        {
            return;
        }

        // avoid recursive updating by ignoring the box's changed event
        box.PasswordChanged -= HandlePasswordChanged;

        string newPassword = (string)e.NewValue;

        if (!GetUpdatingPassword(box))
        {
            box.Password = newPassword;
        }

        box.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
    }

    private static void OnBindPasswordChanged(DependencyObject dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // when the BindPassword attached property is set on a PasswordBox,
        // start listening to its PasswordChanged event

        PasswordBox box = dp as PasswordBox;

        if (box == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool wasBound = (bool)(e.OldValue);
        bool needToBind = (bool)(e.NewValue);

        if (wasBound)
        {
            box.PasswordChanged -= HandlePasswordChanged;
        }

        if (needToBind)
        {
            box.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void HandlePasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PasswordBox box = sender as PasswordBox;

        // set a flag to indicate that we're updating the password
        SetUpdatingPassword(box, true);
        // push the new password into the BoundPassword property
        SetBoundPassword(box, box.Password);
        SetUpdatingPassword(box, false);
    }

    public static void SetBindPassword(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(BindPassword, value);
    }

    public static bool GetBindPassword(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (bool)dp.GetValue(BindPassword);
    }

    public static string GetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (string)dp.GetValue(BoundPassword);
    }

    public static void SetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp, string value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(BoundPassword, value);
    }

    private static bool GetUpdatingPassword(DependencyObject dp)
    {
        return (bool)dp.GetValue(UpdatingPassword);
    }

    private static void SetUpdatingPassword(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
    {
        dp.SetValue(UpdatingPassword, value);
    }
}
 }
```

**Credentials.cs:**

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Text;
       using System.Threading.Tasks;

       namespace LastAndFinalVersion.Commands
   {
    static class Credentials
{
    static System.Collections.Hashtable credentials;
    static Credentials()
    {
        credentials = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
        credentials.Add("Guest", GetHash(0));
        credentials.Add("Administrator", GetHash(11223344));
    }

    internal static bool Check(string login, int pwd)
    {
        return object.Equals(credentials[login], GetHash(pwd));
    }
    static object GetHash(int password)
    {
        return password;
    }
    internal static IEnumerable<string> GetUserNames()
    {
        foreach (string item in credentials.Keys)
            yield return item;
    }
}


}
```

**LoginViewModel.cs:**

```
      using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
      using System.ComponentModel;
      using System.Data.SqlClient;
      using System.Linq;
      using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
      using System.Security;
      using System.Text;
      using System.Threading.Tasks;
      using System.Windows;


   namespace LastAndFinalVersion.ViewModel
{
class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private DelegateCommand loginCommand;
    private  Login _UserName;
    private  Login _pwd;
    private Login CurrentUser { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler OnPropertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public bool IsCurrentUserCredentialsValid { get; private set; }
    public Login UserName
    {
        get { return _UserName; }
        set
        {
            _UserName = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("UserName");
        }


    }


public Login pwd
    {
        get { return _pwd; }
        set
        {
            if(_pwd!=value)
            {
                _pwd = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("pwd");
            }
        }
    }


public LoginViewModel():base()
{
    ButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(SubmitButton);


}
public DelegateCommand ButtonCommand
{
    get { return loginCommand; }
    set
    {
        if (loginCommand != value)
            loginCommand = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonCommand");
    }
}

protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (OnPropertyChanged != null)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

    private object ConvertToUnsecureString(SecureString securePassword)
    {
        if(securePassword==null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        IntPtr unmanagedString = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            unmanagedString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(securePassword);
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(unmanagedString);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(unmanagedString);
        }
    }

    public void SubmitButton()
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(

   @"Data Source= (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=
  C:\Users\User\source\repos\VIAApp2Demo\
  VIAApp2Demo\DB\DatabaseStudents.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect 
  Timeout=30");
    try
    {
        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE UserName=@UserName AND pwd=@pwd";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            SqlParameter Username = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", _UserName);
            if(_UserName==null)
            {
                Username.Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            SqlParameter password = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", _pwd);
            if(_pwd==null)
            {
                password.Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
        if(IsCurrentUserCredentialsValid==true)

        {
                IsCurrentUserCredentialsValid = Credentials.Check(CurrentUser.UserName, CurrentUser.pwd);
            MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
            main.Show();
            main.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect!");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
 }
}
```

And finally my **Login.xaml(View)**:

```
  <Window x:Class="LastAndFinalVersion.View.Login"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LastAndFinalVersion.Helpers"
    xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:LastAndFinalVersion.ViewModel"

    mc:Ignorable="d"
  Title="Login" Height="300" Width="300" FontSize="14" Background="#04c582">
<Window.DataContext>
    <ff:LoginViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Border Background="#2e3137" CornerRadius="20" Margin="20">
    <StackPanel Margin="20">

        <Label Content="Login" 
           Foreground="White" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Separator></Separator>
        <Label Content="Username" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtusername" Text="{Binding UserName}"   
Background="#545d6a" Foreground="White" FontSize="18"/>
        <Label Content="Password"     Foreground="White"/>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" 
                     MaxLength="10"
                local:PasswordHelper.BindPassword="true"
                     local:PasswordHelper.BoundPassword="{Binding 
Path=PasswordBox, Mode=TwoWay, 
ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            PasswordChar="*" 
                     Background="#545d6a" 
                     Foreground="White"
         FontSize="18"/>

        <StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnSubmit" Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand}" 
   Click="btnSubmit_Click"  Content="Submit" Margin="60 10" 
  Background="#545d6a" Foreground="White" FontSize="18"/>
        <TextBlock Height="50" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="24,48,0,0"
               Name="textBlockHeading" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               FontSize="12" 
                  Foreground="Crimson"
               FontStyle="Italic" 
               Padding="5">

        Note: Please login here to view the features of this site. If you 
  are new on this site then <LineBreak /><!--line break-->
        please click on
   <TextBlock>
   <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink_Click"  FontSize="14" 
FontStyle="Normal">Register</Hyperlink>
 </TextBlock>
 button
    </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

</Border>

</Window>
```

**Login.xaml.cs:**

```
 using LastAndFinalVersion.Helpers;
 using LastAndFinalVersion.ViewModel;
 using System.Security;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;

 namespace LastAndFinalVersion.View
 {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Login.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Login : UserControl,IHavePassword
{
   private LoginViewModel lg;
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lg = new LoginViewModel();
        this.DataContext = lg;
    }


    public SecureString Password
    {
        get
        {
            return passwordBox.SecurePassword;
        }
    }
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lg.SubmitButton();
    }

    private void Hyperlink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Register reg = new Register();
        reg.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
  }
```

I would really appreciate some tips about how to check the credentials with the database because I have searched and I found nothing that could work in my case.Also I have an error in Login.xaml.cs saying that I cannot specify different base classes. That's why I have tried to replace Window in Login.xaml with local:UserControl or local:IHavePassword but still didn't work. I'm new in MVVM so any advice would be appreciated.Thank you in advance!

Comment: *Why* do you want to store usernames/passwords at all? Unless you know how to do it, in which case you know you *shouldn't* do it, you'll get it wrong. I don't see 1000 iterations of hashing a salted password in this code. Windows applications *already* know who the logged-in user is and what groups he/she belongs to. The user doesn't have to log in at all. SQL Server provides user accounts too, if eg you have a kiosk environment where the users don't have to log in.

Comment: Hard-coded admin and guest **hashes** just *beg* for someone to open this code with a decompiler and steal them

Comment: Ok @Panagiotis Kanavos ,thank you for the response.I'll try other approach then.

Comment: If you *really* need to implement your own authentication, eg because it's a kiosk application that runs under a single account, check [WPF: Implementing Custom Authentication And Authorization](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25726.wpf-implementing-custom-authentication-and-authorization.aspx). WPF is only relevant as far as the UI is concerned. .NET itself uses the IPrincipal, IIdentity interfaces everywhere. The WindowsIdentity is an implementation of those services. You can create a custom authentication service that implements those interfaces

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos ,Thank you for the info and the tips.I'll try to make the best out of it! :)

Comment: I have tried to do it without credentials,just check the values and it still doesn't work because instead of redirecting me on MainWindow page,it shows the messagebox with the error.How can I make it so that it would work?The method is SubmitButton from LoginViewModel.cs